# Set Value for dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have some problem with my assignment. I try to set value for dropdownlist in GridView when I edit data in this. But when I send my assignment to my friend, he told me he can run it without error ( he uses Visual Studio 2010). I use Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 but I cannot run my code. Please help me.

```
 SqlConnection cn=new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ToString());
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        LoadProduct();
    }
}
public  DataSet LoadCategory()
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from categories", cn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}
private void LoadProduct()
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter("select * from products,categories where products.categoryID=categories.categoryID",cn);
    DataTable db=new DataTable();
    da.Fill(db);
    GridView1.DataSource=db;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    LoadProduct();
}
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    Literal ltr=GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("Literal1") as Literal;
    string categoryname = ltr.Text;
    GridViewRow row=GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
    LoadProduct();
    DropDownList ddl = row.Cells[3].Controls[1] as DropDownList;
    ddl.DataSource = LoadCategory().Tables[0];// when I run there is a error. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
    ddl.DataTextField = "categoryName";
    ddl.DataValueField = "categoryID";
    ddl.DataBind();
    ddl.Items.FindByText(categoryname).Selected = true;        
}
```

Comment: And why can't you run it?  Please give us the exception.

Comment: Assignment? Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ddl.ClearSelection();
ddl.Items.FindByText(categoryname).Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you do it like this in finding your DDL?

```
DropDownList ddl = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("ddl") as DropDownList;
ddl.DataSource = LoadCategory().Tables[0];
```